# Map set of indices to set of Objects, using Java streams

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

Trying to map a set of indices to their corresponding object in a list, then return as a set.

```java
List aList = Arrays.asList(new Object(), new Object(), new Object(), new Object(), new Object(), new Object());

Set.of(0, 2, 3)
     .stream()
     .flatMap(index -> aList.get(index))     // error on this line
     .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

`Error message: no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Object conforms to Stream<? extends R>`

Comment: `map` instead of `flatMap`. And don't declare `aList` as a raw type, use `List<Object>`.

Comment: I can't use List<Object>, as I have to adhere to an already map interface. But thanks map works.

Comment: `Stream.of(0, 2, 3).map(aList::get).collect(Collectors.toSet())` or avoid boxing with `IntStream.of(0, 2, 3).mapToObj(aList::get).collect(Collectors.toSet())`

Answer (score 1):

You need `map` in this example, not `flatMap`. `flatMap` is used when each element of the original `Stream` is mapped to multiple elements.

```
Set.of(0, 2, 3)
  .stream()
  .map(index -> aList.get(index))
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

EDIT: your updated question makes my alternative suggestions obsolete, but the remaining snippet still works.

Comment: Thanks. Also, in the example I am just getting all the elements but, in actuality, I'm getting a subset of the list. So using the constructor like that will be inappropriate.

Comment: Did you read the second sentence of my answer? You can't use `flatMap` to map a single element to a single element (unless you create a Stream of a single element, which is pointless).

Comment: As for your first comment, you should have mentioned that in your question. You can certainly use a Stream with `filter`, but you can still avoid the `map` step (unless the filtering depends on the List index).

Comment: Thanks that's clear, and yes filtering does depend on index.